# unable to install reportlab on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, reportlab

I am trying to install reportlab 2.7 on heroku, but compilation fails.

I spawn a machine with a remote shell and tried to compile it. The error I get when I launch `python setup.py build` is the following

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DRENDERPM_FT -DLIBART_COMPILATION -DLIBART_VERSION="2.3.12" -I/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM -I/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl -I/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1 -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -c /app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-region.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-region.o
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_vpath_bpath.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_rgb_pixbuf_affine.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_rgb_svp.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_svp.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_svp_vpath.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_svp_vpath_stroke.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_svp_ops.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_vpath.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_vpath_dash.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_affine.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_rect.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_rgb_affine.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_rgb_affine_private.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_rgb.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_rgb_rgba_affine.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_svp_intersect.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_svp_render_aa.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_misc.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-parset1.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-dict.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/app/reportlab-2.7/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-region.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/app/.heroku/python/lib -L/app/.heroku/python/lib -lfreetype -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_renderPM.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Why does it fail? I never had this problem with another app I created a year ago.

I suspect the buildpack was changed, but I don't get the difference and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Others are hitting similar problems installing libraries that depend on PIL/Pillow

Comment: I am having the same problem, someone please help!

Comment: I opened a ticket on heroku, let's see what happens

Comment: I had this kind of build problem with Pillow. I was on 2.2.2. Changing my requirements.txt to use 2.4.0 solved it.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143783/error-deploying-on-heroku-reportlab

Comment: @OttavioCampana Any progress on that ticket? Or a link to track it

Comment: They wrote me that they are working on it and it should be fixed soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great news!

The reportlab bug has now been fixed with the `python-2.7.7` runtime.