# Error deploying on Heroku (ReportLab)

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, reportlab

I want to deploy a python / django application on Heroku. In the local environment everything works fine. I use pip to install packages. My requirements.txt is the following:

```
Django==1.6.2
Pillow==2.4.0
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.5
django-ckeditor-updated==4.2.8
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==18.0
html5lib==1.0b3
mongoengine==0.8.7
psycopg2==2.5.2
pyPdf==1.13
pymongo==2.7
pystache==0.5.3
reportlab==3.1.8
six==1.6.1
static==1.0.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
xhtml2pdf==0.0.5
```

But when deploying on Heroku with the command "git push heroku master" I get the error on "ReportLab" installation:

```
           gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-parset1.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-dict.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-region.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_vpath_bpath.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_rgb_pixbuf_affine.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_rgb_svp.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_svp.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_svp_vpath.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_svp_vpath_stroke.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_svp_ops.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_vpath.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_vpath_dash.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_affine.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_rect.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_rgb_affine.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_rgb_affine_private.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_rgb.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_rgb_rgba_affine.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_svp_intersect.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_svp_render_aa.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl/art_misc.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/app/.heroku/python/lib -L/app/.heroku/python/lib -lfreetype -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/_renderPM.so

           /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

           /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value

           collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

           error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

           ----------------------------------------
           Cleaning up...
           Command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-F4RTRK-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_u4591/reportlab
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
        load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
        return command.main(cmd_args)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
        text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 38: ordinal not in range(128)

     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app

    To git@heroku.com:mysterious-oasis-7382.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:mysterious-oasis-7382.git'

Jeromes-MacBook-Pro:diagnosystem_proj Jerome$
```

Your help is appreciated to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by the presence of a static Python 2.7 library in `/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a` ; to install Reportlab on Heroku correctly using the `python-2.7.7` runtime, I changed the order of the directories enumerated by the `__call__` function in the `inc_lib_dirs` class of Reportlab's `setup.py` file as follows:

**Original:**

```python
class inc_lib_dirs:
    L = None
    I = None
    def __call__(self):
        if self.L is None:
            L = []
            I = []
            if platform == "cygwin":
                aDir(L, os.path.join("/usr/lib", "python%s" % sys.version[:3], "config"))
            elif platform == "darwin":
                # attempt to make sure we pick freetype2 over other versions
                aDir(I, "/sw/include/freetype2")
                aDir(I, "/sw/lib/freetype2/include")
                # fink installation directories
                aDir(L, "/sw/lib")
                aDir(I, "/sw/include")
                # darwin ports installation directories
                aDir(L, "/opt/local/lib")
                aDir(I, "/opt/local/include")
            aDir(I, "/usr/local/include")
            aDir(L, "/usr/local/lib")
            aDir(I, "/usr/include")
            aDir(L, "/usr/lib")
            aDir(I, "/usr/include/freetype2")
            prefix = sysconfig.get_config_var("prefix")
            if prefix:
                aDir(L, pjoin(prefix, "lib"))
                aDir(I, pjoin(prefix, "include"))
            self.L=L
            self.I=I
        return self.I,self.L
inc_lib_dirs=inc_lib_dirs()
```

**Edited:**

```python
class inc_lib_dirs:
    L = None
    I = None
    def __call__(self):
        if self.L is None:
            L = []
            I = []
            if platform == "cygwin":
                aDir(L, os.path.join("/usr/lib", "python%s" % sys.version[:3], "config"))
            elif platform == "darwin":
                # attempt to make sure we pick freetype2 over other versions
                aDir(I, "/sw/include/freetype2")
                aDir(I, "/sw/lib/freetype2/include")
                # fink installation directories
                aDir(L, "/sw/lib")
                aDir(I, "/sw/include")
                # darwin ports installation directories
                aDir(L, "/opt/local/lib")
                aDir(I, "/opt/local/include")
            prefix = sysconfig.get_config_var("prefix")
            if prefix:
                aDir(L, pjoin(prefix, "lib"))
                aDir(I, pjoin(prefix, "include"))
            aDir(I, "/usr/local/include")
            aDir(L, "/usr/local/lib")
            aDir(I, "/usr/include")
            aDir(L, "/usr/lib")
            aDir(I, "/usr/include/freetype2")
            self.L=L
            self.I=I
        return self.I,self.L
inc_lib_dirs=inc_lib_dirs()
```

I'd love to find a cleaner solution to avoid keeping a modified version in my egg repository.

Comment: Can someone please explain how to use this solution? Thanks!

Comment: @fabiocorneti: Where am I supposed to edit this code? On my local machine or on Heroku? The error is appearing when I deploy my application with "git push heroku master" and when heroku is installing ReportLab. Per advance thanks for your further help. Does downgrading the python library version to 2.6 will help?

Comment: @jbt_mx I just tried to deploy a new Heroku instance and now Reportlab seems to install correctly, could you try do the same? Maybe the workaround is not needed anymore.

Comment: @fabiocorneti Yes. They just informed me that they've fixed the issued with python 2.7.7 library. Thanks very much for your support.